# How to kill a scheduled task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, kentico-11

In Kentico 11 is there any way to kill a running scheduled task that does not affect other running tasks? The Kentico devnet site only mentions restarting IIS or recycling the app pool, which is suboptimal.

Comment: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-to-kill-a-scheduled-task